# Running 'login' on a USB port?

Tags: usb, login, headless

I have a small headless Linux server that I'd like to login into.  It has an ethernet port, but when I connect it to the network, I do not know what its IP address is to ssh into it.

It also has a USB port, and I was wondering whether there is a way to somehow run 'login' on a USB port so I could connect directly into it from my laptop!?  I know about USB serial port adapters, but it seems like such a waste to go back to RS-232 when I've got my laptop and the small headless computer that both have a USB port on them.

Is there a way to do this, or is it just impossible (either electrically or for lack of a protocol to do this).  Would it be possible to have some sort of a 'virtual' serial port emulator?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Login through a USB port only is unlikely. Can you attach a monitor to the VGA port and a keyboard to USB? Otherwise, can you scan your network to see what new systems (e.g. your server) has attached itself to recently?

Comment: I have just ordered a cable (DTECH USB-USB data transfer cable with a FTDI FT230X chipset) that seems to be a USB-to-USB serial-to-serial cable.  I am hoping that this will allow me to run 'login' on a serial port on the headless server, and just run a terminal emulator (probably just PuTTY) on the laptop.  
I'll let you all know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB is host-to-device, so to connect two USB hosts you need *something* - a USB serial port device, or a USB ethernet device, or whatever.

Connecting to USB hosts via a USB cable is not supported in practice (though the spec for USB-C actually allows it, but I've seen no real implementation of that yet).

> It has an ethernet port, [...] I do not know what its IP address

So give it a static address, or run a DHCP server on your laptop to give it a dynamic address, and login via telnet or ssh.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

So I have received the DTECH DT-6559 USB 'null modem' cable, and it works like a charm:

1. plugged one USB port into my little headless server. The FTDI chip was detected and a /dev/ttyUSB0 virtual serial port was created.
2. Ran getty on that serial port ("sudo systemctl start getty@ttyUSB0") to get a login prompt on the virtual serial port.
3. Connected the other end of the cable into my Windows laptop, which detected the device and enabled the serial port.
4. Ran PuTTY in serial mode on COM4, typed ENTER and got the linux login prompt as expected.

A useful way to log into headless boxes through a USB port to check out their configuration.

Best regards,
Denis